# I am trying for a word-count task using spark-python in which i want the output as the 10 most frequently occuring in a text file

Tags: python, apache-spark

```
newList=[]

def normalizewords(text):

    text = text.replace('_', '').replace('"', '').replace(',', '').replace('.', '')

    text = text.replace('-', '').replace('?', '').replace('!', '').replace("'", "")

    text = text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(':', '').replace('[', '')

    text = text.replace(']', '').replace(';', '')

    return re.compile(r'\W+',re.UNICODE).split(text.lower())

def main():

    file="/user/hduser/input/sample.txt"

    input=sc.textFile(file)

    words=input.flatMap(normalizewords)

    wordsCount=words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

    sortedwordsCount=wordsCount.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x)).sortByKey()

    sorted_final=sortedwordsCount.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x))

    results=sortedwordsCount.collect()

    for result in results:

        count=str(result[0])

        word=result[1].encode('ascii','ignore')

        if(word):

            print word +"\t\t"+ count+"\n"

    sorted_final.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/PythonTask/Result")

    for value in word:

        newList.zip([value,count])

    lengthnewList=str(len(newList))

    print "Length of New List: "+lengthnewList

    return newList

def next():

    mylist=main()

    with open('myfile.txt','w') as out_file:

        out_file.write(newList)

    myfile.close()

next()
```

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/cloudera/PythonTask/sorteddata.py", line 47, in 
>       next()
>
> File "/home/cloudera/PythonTask/sorteddata.py", line 44, in next
>       out_file.write(newList)
>
> TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer,
>   not list

I also don't know how to proceed for list of ten most frequent words and save the output to a text file.

I am stuck. Please help me.

Comment: I vote to close this question qualified as "why my code isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

> File "/home/cloudera/PythonTask/sorteddata.py", line 44, in next **out_file.write(newList)**
>   **TypeError:** argument 1 **must be string** or read-only character buffer, **not list**

The Traceback tells you exactly what the problem is. You are trying to pass a zipped string into the `FILE.write` method. You are supposed to pass a string instead.

It is your choice, on how you want to represent the data while writing to the file. For example in a CSV style format:

```
def next():
    mylist=main()
    with open('myfile.txt','w') as out_file:
        myStr = ''
        for pair in newList:
            myStr += ','.join(map(str, pair)) + '\n'
        out_file.write(myStr)
```

---

**PRO-TIPS**

- You don't need to close a file explicitly when using `with .. open` to open a file. Python will take care of closing the file safely.
- Tracebacks are useful. Learn to read them. They usually contain the line number, method name and the possible error in your file where the program exited unexpectedly.